# Custom Taxonomy specific to a Custom Post type - rewrite URL

Tags: custom-taxonomy, url-rewriting

I have a custom taxonomy which behaves similar to the post type as a category behaves to a the default posts (on the grounds of /%category%/%postname%/ permalink structure) so that the posts in the custom post types are displayed as www.example.com/custom-post-type/custom-taxonomy-name/post-name..

Everything thing works fine except for one element.. the permalink/slug is not correct. The url at this moment is like: www.example.com/behandeling/behandeling_categorie/post-name

The middle part needs be different. It needs to have the term.. not the general taxonomy_name..

This is my code:

```
// Register Custom Post Type
function ats_kliniek_custom_post_type() {

$labels = array(
    'name'                  => _x( 'behandelingen', 'Post Type General Name', 'text_domain' ),
    'singular_name'         => _x( 'behandeling', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
    'menu_name'             => __( 'Behandelingen', 'text_domain' ),
    'name_admin_bar'        => __( 'Behandeling type', 'text_domain' ),
    'archives'              => __( 'behandeling archieven', 'text_domain' ),
    'attributes'            => __( 'behandeling atributen', 'text_domain' ),
    'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Parent behandeling', 'text_domain' ),
    'all_items'             => __( 'Alle behandelingen', 'text_domain' ),
    'add_new_item'          => __( 'Voeg nieuwe behandeling toe', 'text_domain' ),
    'add_new'               => __( 'Voeg nieuwe behandeling toe', 'text_domain' ),
    'new_item'              => __( 'Nieuwe behandeling', 'text_domain' ),
    'edit_item'             => __( 'Bewerkt behandeling', 'text_domain' ),
    'update_item'           => __( 'Werk behandeling bij', 'text_domain' ),
    'view_item'             => __( 'Bekijk behandeling', 'text_domain' ),
    'view_items'            => __( 'Bekijk behandelingen', 'text_domain' ),
    'search_items'          => __( 'Zoek behandelingen', 'text_domain' ),
    'not_found'             => __( 'Behandeling niet gevonden', 'text_domain' ),
    'not_found_in_trash'    => __( 'Geen behandelingen gevonden in prullenbak', 'text_domain' ),
    'featured_image'        => __( 'Uitgelichte afbeelding', 'text_domain' ),
    'set_featured_image'    => __( 'Stel uitgelichte behandeling in', 'text_domain' ),
    'remove_featured_image' => __( 'Verwijder uitgelichte behandeling', 'text_domain' ),
    'use_featured_image'    => __( 'Gebruik als uitgelichte behandeling', 'text_domain' ),
    'insert_into_item'      => __( 'Plaats in behandeling', 'text_domain' ),
    'uploaded_to_this_item' => __( 'Uploaded to this item', 'text_domain' ),
    'items_list'            => __( 'Behandelingen lijst', 'text_domain' ),
    'items_list_navigation' => __( 'Behandelingen lijst navigatie', 'text_domain' ),
    'filter_items_list'     => __( 'Filter behandelingen lijst', 'text_domain' ),
);
$rewrite = array(
    'slug'                  => 'behandelingen/behandeling_categorie',
    'with_front'            => false,
    'pages'                 => true,
    'feeds'                 => true,
);
$args = array(
    'label'                 => __( 'behandeling', 'text_domain' ),
    'description'           => __( 'behandeling custom post type', 'text_domain' ),
    'labels'                => $labels,
    'supports'              => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'custom-fields', ),
    'taxonomies'            => array( 'behandeling_categorie' ),
    'hierarchical'          => true,
    'public'                => true,
    'show_ui'               => true,
    'show_in_menu'          => true,
    'menu_position'         => 5,
    'show_in_admin_bar'     => false,
    'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
    'can_export'            => true,
    'has_archive'           => 'behandelingen',
    'exclude_from_search'   => false,
    'publicly_queryable'    => true,
    'rewrite'               => $rewrite,
    'capability_type'       => 'page',
);
register_post_type( 'behandelingen', $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'ats_kliniek_custom_post_type', 0 );

// Register Custom Taxonomy
function ats_kliniek_custom_taxonomy() {

$labels = array(
    'name'                       => _x( 'behandeling categorieën', 'Taxonomy General Name', 'text_domain' ),
    'singular_name'              => _x( 'behandeling categorie', 'Taxonomy Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
    'menu_name'                  => __( 'Behandeling categorie', 'text_domain' ),
    'all_items'                  => __( 'Alle behandeling categorieën', 'text_domain' ),
    'parent_item'                => __( 'Parent categorie', 'text_domain' ),
    'parent_item_colon'          => __( 'Parent categorie:', 'text_domain' ),
    'new_item_name'              => __( 'Nieuwe behandeling categorie', 'text_domain' ),
    'add_new_item'               => __( 'Voeg nieuwe behandeling categorie toe', 'text_domain' ),
    'edit_item'                  => __( 'Bewerk categorie', 'text_domain' ),
    'update_item'                => __( 'Update categorie', 'text_domain' ),
    'view_item'                  => __( 'Bekijk categorie', 'text_domain' ),
    'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate items with commas', 'text_domain' ),
    'add_or_remove_items'        => __( 'Voeg of verwijderen categorieën', 'text_domain' ),
    'choose_from_most_used'      => __( 'Kies van meest gebruikte', 'text_domain' ),
    'popular_items'              => __( 'Populaire categorieën', 'text_domain' ),
    'search_items'               => __( 'Zoeken behandeling categorieën', 'text_domain' ),
    'not_found'                  => __( 'Geen behandeling categorieën gevonden', 'text_domain' ),
    'no_terms'                   => __( 'Geen behandeling categorieën', 'text_domain' ),
    'items_list'                 => __( 'Geen behandeling categorieën lijst', 'text_domain' ),
    'items_list_navigation'      => __( 'behandeling categorieën lijst navigatie', 'text_domain' ),
);
$rewrite = array(
    'slug'                       => 'behandelingen',
    'with_front'                 => false,
    'hierarchical'               => true,
);
$args = array(
    'labels'                     => $labels,
    'hierarchical'               => true,
    'public'                     => true,
    'show_ui'                    => true,
    'show_admin_column'          => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
    'show_tagcloud'              => true,
    'rewrite'                    => $rewrite,
);
register_taxonomy( 'behandeling_categorie', array( 'behandelingen' ), $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'ats_kliniek_custom_taxonomy', 0 );


function ats_kliniek_filter_post_type_link($link, $post)
{
if ($post->post_type != 'behandelingen')
    return $link;

if ($cats = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'behandeling_categorie'))
    $link = str_replace('%behandeling_categorie%', array_pop($cats)->slug, $link);
return $link;
}
add_filter('post_type_link', 'ats_kliniek_filter_post_type_link', 10, 2);
```

Do you guys see what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, from what I can see, the reason for your wrong middle part is that it is hard coded in the slug?

```
'slug'                  => 'behandelingen/behandeling_categorie',
```

Comment: Thx.. i've changed it to: 'behandelingen/%behandeling_categorie%'